# Docker - workflow for updating container

Tags: docker

I'm just getting to grips with Docker. I need to update a base image for my image.

**Questions**

- Do I need to completely recreate all the changes I made on top of the
  new base image and save it as a new image?
- What do people do to remember the changes they've made to their
  image?

Comment: It's unclear what you really ask for (vide `the changes I made on top of the new base image`. Can you include your sample `Dockerfile` ? As for the other question, you don't make any changes inside the container, you are supposed to update your `Dockerfile` when you need something new/changed. `Container != VM`. This is because any change inside the container (eg. new package installed) is lost when the container is recreated.

Comment: I'm just trying to understand it at the moment, so I don't have a dockerfile yet, but I think I get it.

My process is that I've downloaded a built image of some software. I started the container based on the image. Inside the container is a config file that needs to be edited, which I edited using SSH. I then committed the changes to a new image.

But if the developer of the original image publishes a new version, do I need to download the new image then re-edit the config file by hand using SSH again, then re-commit to a new image and run a new container?

Comment: Don't edit running containers like that (even if it is possible to commit the changes afterwards). Create your own Dockerfile and copy new config to the appropriate location inside of the image. When a new version is published, you can just change the `FROM` statement and rebuild the image (as long as the new version is compatible with the old one)

Comment: Brilliant, that makes sense. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

> Do I need to completely recreate all the changes I made on top of the new base image and save it as a new image?

You don't. It is up to you whether you want to completely rebuild the image or to use your old one as a new base but unless we are talking about generic base image, such as one where you just preinstall things that you want available to all the derived images, it is probably better to just rebuild the image from scratch, otherwise you might end up cluttering images with stuff they don't need which is never a good thing (both from the perspective of size and security).

> What do people do to remember the changes they've made to their image?

Right out of the box you can use history command to see what went into the image

```
docker image history <image>
```

which lists image's filesystem layers.

Personally, when I build images, I copy Dockerfile to the image so that I can quickly `cat` it.

```
docker exec <image> cat Dockerfile
```

It is more convenient for me than listing through the history output (I don't include anything sensitive in a dockerfile and all the information that it has is already available within the container if someone breaks in).